# Google PubSub - serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com doesn't exist

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub

I am trying to subscribe to Gmail for mail notifications using Google's Pub/Sub and I've gone through the documentation and tutorials provided by Google. At one point, [the docs](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push#pubsub_grant_access) state that I need to publish the correct rights to my PubSub topic:

> You need to grant `publish` privileges to `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`. You can do this using the Cloud Pub/Sub Developer Console permissions interface following the resource-level access control instructions.

My understanding is that the `publish` privilege is equivalent to `pubsub.topics.publish` or just "PubSub Publisher". But what about the `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`? I cant' find that service account anywhere and the console is not letting me create it due to character restrictions. Is there another way to get this account?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You do not need to create the gmail service account, it already exists. You are correct about “granting publish privileges” as the same as “Pub/Sub Publisher”.

Under the topic permissions interface, I would pass in the service account `gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`   (note: take out the leading “`serviceAccount:`” part) in the ‘new members’ field, and select “Pub/Sub Publisher” as the role.

I am guessing you couldn’t find the service account because you were looking up `serviceAccount:gmail-api-push@system.gserviceaccount.com`.

Comment: You're my hero! That was it. And your assumption of what I was putting in was correct (i.e. including `serviceAccount:`)

Answer (score 5):

Permissions are set by Pub/Sub Topic in the Pub/Sub Topics section of the GCP Console.

- Go to the Google Cloud Console.
- From the Hamburger menu, go to Big Data -> Pub/Sub -> Topics.
  Shortcut to this location: https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/cloudpubsub/topicList
- Click the checkbox for the Topic.
- At the right side of the console, select "SHOW INFO PANEL".
- Click Add members
- Enter the service account and select the desired role. Usually Pub/Sub Publisher.