# google pub/sub: User not authorized to perform this action

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, gmail-api, google-cloud-pubsub, google-cloud-iam

I am trying to get a new email notification on my backend server using google pub/sub service.

steps:

1. I have created a topic.
2. Created a push subscription and added my backend API endpoint
3. using postman I have generated an OAuth token with all Gmail scope.

> If I am publishing messages from GCP UI to my topic. I am getting data on my backend server.

problem:

1. I am trying to use this API using postman and getting errors:

- API doc: https://any-api.com/googleapis_com/gmail/docs/users/gmail_users_watch
- API endpoint: [https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/{userId}/watch](https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/%7BuserId%7D/watch)
- body:{
  "topicName": "",
  "labelFilterAction": "include",
  "labelIds": [
  ]
  }
- error:

  ```
   {
   "code": 403,

   "message": "Error sending test message to Cloud PubSub projects/app- 
               119/topics/testing-topic : User not authorized to perform this action."
   }
  ```

> permission was given to current user as owner of topic Any suggestion why user not authorized ?

Comment: do you also include the Google Cloud scopes in addition of the Gmail scopes?

Comment: I got the solution in this post **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767992/google-pubsub-serviceaccountgmail-api-pushsystem-gserviceaccount-com-doesnt?answertab=votes#tab-top**